# Стандарты HTML и CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Есть какой-то официальный источник со всеми стандартами HTML5 и CSS на русском языке?

Comment: Могу предложить неплохую документацию на http://htmlbook.ru/ .

Comment: @erm да вот я смотрел там и гуглил , самих стандартов не нашел , есть ссылка ?

Comment: Проще выучить английский, чем постоянно искать документацию на русском. В большинстве случаев документация есть только на английском.

Comment: Чем вам не нравятся английские источники

Comment: могу сказать что `<li>` и `<p>` закрывать необязательно

Comment: @Duoxx верно , и тогда если li будет inline-block то даже в этом случае не будет расстояние между списками

Comment: мне всегда помагаєт етот сайт https://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MDN или MSDN в основном пользуюсь MDN

Answer (score 2):

Со всеми - врятли. Для меня хорошим справочником является [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Reference). Часто там приводят ссылки на стандарты. Но переводом на русский занимаются волонтеры, соответственно не на все есть перевод.

Comment: Да я вот не могу понять один момент , поэтому и хотел изучить...
Валидатор ругается на меня , если я внутри блока, вставляю css между тегами <style></style> , а на сайт Google не ругается , хоть он делает именно так...
Яндекс же , стили вставляет в шапку , но google pagespeed будет ругаться на такой способ.
Какой то замкнутый круг(((

Comment: @Vipz, вставляйте `<style type="text/css">` и не будет ругаться. Но не советовал бы прислушиваться к мнению валидатора. Лучше считать, что хороший хтмл тот - который понимается большинством браузеров (ну и теги закрыты в довесок).

Comment: @Vipz так что ж вы не задали вопрос именно об этой проблеме?

Answer (score 0):

На счет русского языка не знаю, но на английском есть [сайт](https://www.w3.org/) Консорциума Всемирной Паутины, который и принимает эти стандарты, там же есть html и css валидаторы. Там же где-то были переводы на другие языки, но вроде бы не всё и не на все языки переведено.